# Replace Newline And Following Whitespaces Until A Specific String In A File

Tags: perl, unix, sed

How can I replace newline and following whitespaces until a specific string using one-liner **sed** or **perl**?

e.g. I want to replace newline and following whitespaces before a string 'XYZ' in a file. All line starting with word 'XYZ' will be appended before previous line (with one extra whitespace).

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    XXX lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  DDD lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
cccc lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

   XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

the output will be

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    XXX lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  DDD lorem ipsum dolor sit amet XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
cccc lorem ipsum dolor sit amet XYZ lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: It's not a homework. It's just I rarely code in terminal, and I need some kind of swiss knife for something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -0777pe's/\n\s*(?=XYZ)/ /g' file
```

`-0777` causes the entire file to be considered one line.

The command as written will output to STDOUT, which you can redirect as you please. `-i~` and `-i` will edit "in place", with and without backup respectively.

Comment: Ah, turns out I missed the `-0777`. I tried similar regex but it didn't give the effect I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `BEGIN { $/ = undef; }` would have done the trick more verbosely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`s/[\s\n]+XYZ/ XYZ/gsm;`